# Second Ionisation Energy in d Block elements

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ionization-energy

> The second ionisation energy is expected to be highest for element
>   with atomic number:
>
> 1. 22
> 2. 24
> 3. 25
> 4. 30

I had expected the answer to be option 2 because the second electron has to be removed from the stable half filled $\ce{3d}$ configuration. But the answer is option 4.